# How to write to a CSV file with pandas while appending to the next empty row without writing the columns again?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
# df1
 Id  A  B  C
  3  4  5  6
```

I wrote this to a csv and it works great the first time,
however when I append the CSV it rewrites the columns and the values again

like this:

```
 Id  A  B  C
  3  4  5  6
 Id  A  B  C
  3  4  5  6
```

Is there a method for the 2nd iteration afterwards to only write the value and not the columns when writing to a csv through pandas?

I have tried using the 'a' command for appending and to empty my dataframe so it's just the columns to use as a header to write to the csv and then the as a separate dataframe append the values however pandas does not allow for empty dataframes

Answer (score 2):

Set **`header=False`** option for each **next** `df.to_csv` call to exclude column names from record.

Answer (score 2):

Use this snippet. Check if the file already exists: if not use `header=True` for the first time else use `header=False` to avoid duplicate headers:

```
import os.path

def to_csv(df, csvfile):
    header = False
    if not os.path.exists(csvfile):
        header=True
    df.to_csv(csvfile, header=header, index=False, mode='a')

to_csv(df1, csvfile)
```